# python csv subcombinations columns

Tags: python

I have csv file like this:

```
F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,label

a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,L1

b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,L2
```

I want to have the combination of columns into the file as follows:

-For a column combination with the label and write the expected results to:

file1:

```
F1,label

a1,L1

b1,L2
```

file2:

```
F2,label

a2,L1

b2,L2
```

until

file10:

```
F10,label

a10,L1

b10,L2
```

-For 2 column combinations with the label and write the expected results to:

2C_file1:

```
F1,F2,label

a1,a2,L1

b1,b2,L2
```

2C_file2:

```
F1,F3,label

a1,a3,L1

b1,b3,L2
```

until

45C_file45:

```
F9,F10,label

a9,a10,L1

b9,b10,L2
```

-For 3 columns combinations with the label and write to 120 files:

.....until.....

-For 9 columns combinations with the label and write to 10 files:

-For 10 columns combinations with the label and write to 1 files:

I have searched and I found a python code for string combination with itertool.
How could I archive above tasks with python code?

```
import itertools as iters

text='ABCDEFGHIJ'

C1= iters.combinations(text,1)

print list(C1)

C2= iters.combinations(text,2)

print list(C2)
.....
C9= iters.combinations(text,9)

print list(C9)

C10=iters.combinations(text,10)

print list(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop structure should be able to create the structure you would like to have. It has to be changed to write to files. Here the length of the generated sequence or the position of the output that was generated is part of the same structure that you would like to print into a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

row1 = ["F{i}".format(i=i) for i in range(1,11)]
row1.append("label")

row2 = ["a{i}".format(i=i) for i in range(1,11)]
row2.append("L1")

row3 = ["b{i}".format(i=i) for i in range(1,11)]
row3.append("L2")

for SequenceLength in range(1, len(row1)):
    for SequencePositionStart in range(len(row1)):
        if row1[SequencePositionStart:SequenceLength] == []:
            continue
        print(','.join(row1[SequencePositionStart:SequenceLength]), row1[-1], sep=",")
        print(','.join(row2[SequencePositionStart:SequenceLength]), row2[-1], sep=",")
        print(','.join(row3[SequencePositionStart:SequenceLength]), row3[-1], sep=",")
```